# Displacement inverted with Cycles and Eevee with a regular Displacement node

Tags: texturing, node-editor, displacement

Eevee and Cycles inverts the Displacement.  It didn't do that before. I suspect there is a setting somewhere that fixes this.

[image]

Take any displacement map and displace it in Cycles.
[image]

[image]

Now if you go into Eevee its reversed.
[image]

If you turn it around it looks normal.

[image]

Comment: Displacement doesn't work for Eevee, only for Cycles, also it's not supposed to be plugged into the Surface input of your Material Output

Comment: @moonboots I guess he uses the _Surface_ output as a kind of viewer node (which does work if he does it like that). However, I cannot reproduce it, in my Blender 3.2.2 they both look the same. Only that in _Eevee_ nothing gets displaced of course.